# Codec issue while reading txt file via Python

Tags: python, string, utf-8

Having an issue while trying to open .txt file (which contains only pure text in it) with Python 3.6 using simple `open ()` approach:

```
with open('3003.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
```

It gives the errortrace like that:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 182: invalid continuation byte
```

I used couple of googled approaches but they dont solve the deal. What should be done to solve this?

Comment: What version of python do you use: 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: 3.6, just as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: add `encoding='latin-1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python 3 `open()` style file handler which streams bytestrings:

```
open('3003.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
```

Note the 'b' meaning binary mode